# Как передать управление интернет-магазином на Django другому человеку (чтобы он добавлял товары и видел заказы, как я сейчас)?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, heroku, ecommerce

Сделал интернет-магазин на Django. Буду разворачивать его на Heroku.
Как мне передать управление магазином другому человеку (чтобы он добавлял товары и видел заказы через админку django, как это сейчас делаю я) ?
Просто передать логин и пароль админки Django ?
Или как-то передать управление через Heroku ?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 4):

> Просто передать логин и пароль админки Django ?

Передавать данные своей учётной записи - дело небезопасное, наблагодарное и довольно глупое.
Django позволяет создавать несколько учётных записей суперпользователей, для этого в директории проекта [В виртуальном окружении] нужно прописать:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Дальше нужно следовать инструкциям, которые будут отображаться в консоли. Выбрать имя пользователя, пароль и прочие данные учётной записи.
После этого данные можно передавать другому человеку.

Кроме того, в целях безопасности проекта (не только от человека, которому вы даёте доступ) предоставлять все права пользователю, которому попросту не нужны **все** права нежелательно.

После создания пользователя в админке Django вы можете редактировать созданного пользователя. Настоятельно рекомендую снять право суперпользователя и выдать необходимые права вручную (или создать группу, в неё собрать нужные права и выдать пользователю эту группу)

---

Кроме прочего, имея статус суперпользователя [или соответствующие права], вы можете самостоятельно создавать новых пользователей прямо в админке, не прибегая к созданию пользователей через консоль.